# On the Thingsboard k8s deployment version, how can I change the `JWT_TOKEN_EXPIRATION_TIME`?

Tags: jwt, iot, thingsboard

I deployed [Thignsboard](https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard-ce-k8s/tree/master/helm) with helm charts a five-month ago, and it's already integrated with my company's system. However, we need to change the `JWT_TOKEN_EXPIRATION_TIME` from default to more than a month.

I found the below UI from the latest Thingsboard version but I cannot find the same UI from the integrated Thingsboard.

[UI of the previous Thingsboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzurJ.png)

The integrated Thingsboard shows the below UI. There are no JWT security settings.
[UI of the latest Thingsboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvwpO.png)

I tried to find the `JWT_TOKEN_EXPIRATION_TIME` ENV from every deployed Thingsboard container, but I cannot find any ENVs related to the time.

Now, I cannot update the deployed Thingsboard because it can affect our system. How can I change the token time?

Comment: both pictures of the previous and latest Thingsboard you posted are the same

Comment: According to [their website](https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/ui/jwt-security-settings/) you should be able to scroll down in the Security Settings to find the JWT settings including the expiration time.

Have you considered it might be some kind of permission issue? Are you a privileged enough administrator?

Comment: Did you also try running
`helm inspect values thingsboard`
and looking for jwt options? (this is from their github readme)

Answer (score 0):

Since thingsboard 3.4.2 you can change setting value from DB.

Default value of `JWT_TOKEN_EXPIRATION_TIME` is used from `/usr/share/thingsboard/conf/thingsboard.conf` or environment.

Adding env variable to deployment.yaml like below will work.

```yaml
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: thingsboard-node-config
      containers:
        - name: thingsboard
          env:
            - name: JWT_TOKEN_EXPIRATION_TIME
              value: '90000000' #<-- change this
```